# How to pass all form elements in ajax without specifying name

Tags: html, ajax

In my aplication I have a dynamically generated form. On a button click I have to send all these form elements to another page using Ajax. Since the form is dynamically gernerated, I cannot specify the form element names while calling ajax.

Is there any way to pass all the form elements without specifying element names in Ajax. May be as an array of elements.

Comment: Are you using jQuery at all? If so, `$('form').serialize();` creates a `&name=value&name2=value` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post('ajaxurl', $('#form_id').serialize(), function(data) {
     // do something with data
});
```